# Adjust div size to match space left by other divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Basically what I want to do is to stick one div with fixed width to the right side, stick one div with fixed height to the bottom side and have one div fill the space that is left. The third div should automatically wrap text as well and the other divs should adjust their respective height and width to the container.

Here is what I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/u0owp3jy/1/

```css
 body {
       background-color: black;
       box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #wrapper {
       display: table;
       width: 50%;
       height: 300px;
       margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
       border: solid;
       border-width: 3px;
       border-color: red;
    }

    #flex {
       background-color: blue;
       /*width: calc(100% - 170px);*/
       width: auto;
       float: left;
       display: table-row; 
       height: 100%;
       padding: 10px;
       overflow-y: auto;
    }

    #static-left {
       background-color: yellow;
       float: right;
       display: table-row; 
       height: 100%;

       width: 140px;
       border-left: solid;
       border-width: 3px;
       border-color: red;
       overflow-y: auto;
    }

    #static-bottom {
       display: table-row;
       background-color: green;
       height: 50px;
       width: 100%;
       border-top: solid;
       border-width: 3px;
       border-color: red;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
       <div id="flex"></div>

       <div id="static-left"></div>

       <div id="static-bottom"></div>
    </div>
```

The thing with this is, that to get the correct width for the flexible div, I need to use calc() which is bad and another thing is, that the border of the bottom div is not displayed.

Also, textwrapping does not work if you have `width: auto;` apparently.
If possible I'd like to do this with css only. It should also work on mobile browsers.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: That said...is the structure fixed?...This is pretty simple if we can tweak the structure slightly.

Comment: Basically what I need is kind of a resizable chat window with the right being a user list of static width, the bottom being a text input of static height and the other one being the main text display.

I don't know how much it needs to be tweaked. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following solution. I solved this with using flexbox. Additionaly I did some optimization to your CSS to get cleaner and better CSS code.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.top-wrapper {
  align-items:stretch;
  align-self:flex-start;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  height:100%;
  max-height:250px;
  width:100%;
}
#wrapper {
  align-items:stretch;
  border:3px solid #f00;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  height:300px;
  margin:10px auto 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:50%;
}
#flex {
  background-color:blue;
  flex-grow:1;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:10px;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
#static-left {
   background-color:yellow;
   border-left:3px solid #f00;
   overflow-y:auto;
   width:140px;
}
#static-bottom {
  background-color:green;
  border-top:3px solid #f00;
  box-sizing:content-box;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="top-wrapper">
    <div id="flex">
      asdddddddddddd dddd dfdfd dfdfdfd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
    </div>
    <div id="static-left">
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
      asd<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="static-bottom">
    asd<br/>
    asd<br/>
    asd<br/>
    asd<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you can find the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/0ypmw3xz/

Comment: Thank you very much. I still need to wrap my head around flexbox ...
Btw, somehow the verson from before the edit seems to work but the edited one eats the bottom div.

Is it also possible to wrap the text of the flex div when it gets too long, or do I need to do this in javascript?

Comment: You changed the `max-height:250px;` in your code to `height:100%;` and now when I copy it, it bottom div is not displayed anymore. If I change it back, it works.

The word wrap works like a charm, thank you.